# MySQL Update Table Field - Moving Strings

Tags: mysql

I have been reading through this page with no luck:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html

I cannot find out how to move a group of strings from one field to another.
Can anyone shed some light please.

Here is what I want to do:

Current Table:

```
+----+---------+-------------------+  
| post_content |    post_title     |    
+----+---------+-------------------+         
| -td- -/td-   | MSOR-RUST-NAVY    |  
| -td- -/td-   | NBLA-SAND-SAND    |         
| -td- -/td-   | SHZA-IVORY-BLACK  |             
| -td- -/td-   | UKRN-IVORY-RUST   |          
+----+---------+-------------------+
```

End Goal:

```
+----+--------------+---------------+  
| post_content      | post_title    |    
+----+--------------+---------------+         
| -td- MSOR -/td-   | -RUST-NAVY    |  
| -td- NBLA -/td-   | -SAND-SAND    |         
| -td- SHZA -/td-   | -IVORY-BLACK  |             
| -td- UKRN -/td-   | -IVORY-RUST   |          
+----+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether it is the best way or not but you can try this:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, ' ', 1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_title, '-', 1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, ' ', -1)) AS post_content,
  CONCAT('-', SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_title, '-', -2)) AS post_title
FROM tablename
```

And if the content in `post_content` will always be `-td- MSOR -/td-` the try this:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT('-td-', SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_title, '-', 1), '-/td-') AS post_content,
  CONCAT('-', SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_title, '-', -2)) AS post_title
FROM tablename
```

> Edit 1: So how would I update the field post_content to the new value?

```
UPDATE tablename
SET
  post_content = CONCAT('-td-', SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_title, '-', 1), '-/td-'),
  post_title = CONCAT('-', SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_title, '-', -2))
```

Comment: So how would I update the field post_content to the new value? Would I add "UPDATE" infront?

Comment: What happens when post_content has other strings in the field: -td-Cars -/td-   -td- -/td-. Then how can I SET post_content without deleting other contents in the field? Would I have to use the REPLACE function?

Comment: @LouiIsMyDog Better update your quest and add all possible data.

Comment: UPDATE wp_posts

SET 
  post_content = REPLACE (post_content,'<td>  </td>',CONCAT('<td>', SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_title, '-', 1), '</td>')),
  post_title = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_title, '-', -2))
 where ID BETWEEN 359 AND 429;

Comment: Thank you! You have been very helpful!

Comment: @LouiIsMyDog Glad you made it. :)